# Oracle 11.2g 64 Bit on Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: oracle

I have installed 64 bit oracle (11.2g) on my windows server 2012 R2 64 bit. All works fine with sqlplus.

Now my software is still 32 bit and when I try and connect, it get an error "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.".

Is this because I am trying to connect 32 bit software with 64 bit oracle? Or something else might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install an oracle 11G 32 bit client in another Oracle home.

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately I still get the problem